# Opencv: save a double matrix with imwrite

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I have a matrix (Mat) constituted by double, in the range [0,1].
When I save it by means of command imwrite, the resulting image is totally black.
I suppose the problem is a casting problem, but I don't know how to solve it.
Thanks

Comment: try `cv::imwrite(filename, yourmatrix*255)`
Otherwise have a look at http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imwrite#imwrite since some file extensions allow only limited data types.

Answer (score 2):

The only way for OpenCV to store array of doubles without converting them to other formats (and losing information) is by using [FileStorage](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html?highlight=filestorage#filestorage). [imwrite](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imwrite#imwrite) is restricted to arrays of 'char' or 'short'.

Answer (score 1):

You get the totally black image is because all images pixels are within range `[0,1]` (actually either 0 or 1 when saving to image), which is approaching total black (either for gray-scale image or color image).

To save the matrix to the image with *normal* color, you need first to transform the double matrix to range `[0, 255]` by multiplying each value by `255`. Remember to transform back if you later load the matrix from this image by dividing each value by `255`.

Comment: I think you have to do a `convertTo (converted_Mat , CV_8U or CV_16U , 255 or 65535)` to have also the type proper set.